# Which XML comment tags Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Help Page should I use on a controller methods?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xml-documentation, asp.net-web-api-helppages, maml

I am trying to build API documentation for a RESTful web service using [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Help Page 5.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/). It looks like the contents of the `<summary>` and `<param>` elements get included in the documentation, but the `<remarks>` section is totally ignored, and where I would expect the description of `<returns>`, I see a duplicate of `<summary>`. I could not find any article explaining which XML comment tags Help Page supports (or how commenting controllers is different from commenting regular code). I am wondering if someone could share any pointers, in particular, which tags can be used, how to reference other pages, etc.